# SQL max condition in double join

Tags: sql, join, max

So we have 3 relevant tables:

- `book` with attributes `title, numberofpages`
- `person` with `last name` and `id`
- `writes` with `author` (= `person.id`) and `book` (= `book.title`)

So we want to find the last name of each person who is an author and the number of pages of his book with the highest page number.

We tried this:

```
SELECT lastname, numberofpages
FROM book, person, writes 
WHERE person.id=writes.author AND book.title=writes.book
```

this returns:

```
author A  number of pages of his book 1
author A  number of pages of his book 2
author B  number of pages of his book 1
```

and so on...

How can we make it that it only gives one row per author which contains only the number of pages of the book with the highest number? We tried all kinds of subselects with `max(numberofpages)` but can't get it to work.

Comment: It is a very poor practice to use implicit joins. Learn to use explicit joins. They are less prone to error and far easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `group by` clause like this:

```
select p.lastname, max(w.numberofpages)
from writes w
inner join person p on p.id = w.author
inner join books b on b.title = w.book
group by p.lastname, p.id
```

Comment: @pltm_dev no problem m8 :) you should vote up to the answers that are correct and accept one.

Comment: @aF. the OP may not have enough reputation to upvote (I think he needs at least 15 points). Voting up his question should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by the author, and pick the `max`:

```
SELECT person.lastname, max(book.numberofpages)
FROM book, person, writes 
WHERE person.id=writes.author AND book.title=writes.book
GROUP BY person.lastname, person.id
```

You should also consider using a modern join syntax, and preserve info about authors with different IDs but the same last name:

```
SELECT person.lastname, max(book.numberofpages)
FROM book
JOIN writes ON book.title=writes.book
JOIN person ON person.id=writes.author
GROUP BY person.id, person.lastname
```

Comment: Will fail if multiple authors have the same last name. Also suggest using ansi-92 `join` syntax

Comment: @MartinSmith This looks like a toy project (AKA "homework") because joining in general is done on non-ID fields. I tried modifying author's SQL as little as possible (and I did add the ANSI-92 join section)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT person.lastname, max(writes.numberofpages)
FROM book, person, writes  
WHERE person.id=writes.author AND book.title=writes.book 
GROUP BY person.lastname, person.id
```